# Indentation and new line command for XMLwriter in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am writing some data to XML file...but when I open it all the values are in a single line...how can write it in readable format?ie each node in new line and indentation?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.xml", FileMode.Create);

XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

w.WriteStartDocument();
w.WriteStartElement("myfile");                 

w.WriteElementString("id", id.Text);
w.WriteElementString("date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
w.WriteElementString("version", ver.Text);
w.WriteEndElement();
w.WriteEndDocument();
w.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a `XmlTextWriter` instead of `XmlWriter` and then set the `Indentation` properties.

**Example**

```
string filename = "MyFile.xml";

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
{
  xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  xmlWriter.Indentation = 4;

  // ... Write elements
}
```

Following @jumbo comment, this could also be implemented like in .NET 2.

```
var filename = "MyFile.xml";
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() 
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "    "
}

using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
{
    // ... Write elements
}
```

Comment: except then you can't set the XmlSettings property if needed

Comment: Use of XmlTextWriter is [no longer recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) (since .Net2.0). See [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075559/what-is-the-purpose-of-xmltextwriter-if-xmlwriter-is-the-recommended-one) for further info.

Answer (score 34):

You need to first create an XmlWriterSettings object that specifies your indentation, then when creating your XmlWriter, pass in the XmlWriterSettings after your path.

Additionally, I use the `using` block to let C# handle the disposing of my resources so that I don't need to worry about losing any resources on an exception.

```
{
  XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
  {
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t",
    NewLineOnAttributes = true
  };

  using (XmlWriter w= XmlWriter.Create("myfile.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
  {
    w.WriteStartDocument();
    w.WriteStartElement("myfile");

    w.WriteElementString("id", id.Text);
    w.WriteElementString("date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
    w.WriteElementString("version", ver.Text);
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.WriteEndDocument();
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically, setting "`Indent`" to true is all you need here to have the `Xml(Text?)Writer` emit new lines.

Answer (score 8):

Check the Settings property:

```
w.Settings.Indent = true;
```

Edit: You can't set it directly:

```
System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create("path", new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings())
```

Comment: exception:The 'XmlWriterSettings.Indent' property is read only and cannot be set

Comment: My fault, you need to use the "Create" method and pass it in directly; updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Formatting Property of the XmlTextWriter:

```
TextWriter textWriter;
var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: What version of .NET (or assembly?) is this "`Formatting`" property in? My solution targets 4.5.1, and doesn't know about any "`Formatting`" property on `Xml(Text?)Writer`?

Comment: XmlTextWriter has been deprecated since .net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Use Settings As follow:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (XmlWriter xmlDoc = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings)){
         // logic here..
        }
```

This will get you where you want, though, you don't have to use MemoryStream, the importent part is the settings.

Answer (score 0):

A little VB.NET version using XmlWriter plus XmlWriterSettings direct to file:

```
Dim oSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyType), New XmlRootAttribute("MyRootAttributeName"))
Using oXmlWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("MyFilePath", New XmlWriterSettings With {.Indent = True}) //Default encoding is utf-8
    oSerializer.Serialize(oXmlWriter, oInstanceOfMyType)
    oXmlWriter.Flush()
End Using
```

Check the doco for other settings and file overwrite options but this is clean and works as expected in lots of situations.