# What is the purpose of xmltextwriter if xmlwriter is the recommended one

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkz7cs0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Although the Microsoft .NET Framework includes the XmlTextWriter class, which is a concrete implementation of the XmlWriter class, in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, the recommended practice is to create XmlWriter instances using the Create method.

So if we have to use XmlWriter anyhow what is the purpose of having XmlTextWriter?
why do it exist?

Answer (score 5):

[`XMLWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is an abstract class which acts as the base type for all XML writers. It was introduced with .NET 1.1. [`XMLTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) is one of many possible implementations of `XMLWriter`, specifically to create a text representation. It was also introduced with .NET 1.1.

Now, in .NET 2, the `XMLWriter` class was extended to contain additional static `Create` methods, e.g. [`XMLWriter.Create(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kcsse48t.aspx) to write the XML to a file. These methods create an object of an internal type that implements `XMLWriter` (so the actual type it uses is not visible). That way, you don’t have to worry about the actual implementation but can just use the common base type, `XMLWriter`, to use it.

Those `Create` methods could replace the previous `XMLTextWriter` completely, but since the .NET framework wants to remain backwards compatible, it had to keep the `XMLTextWriter` although the `XMLWriter` is now capable of handling those cases.

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlTextWriter` class is one of the implementations of the `XmlWriter` abstract class.

The text is somewhat misleading, as it's not actually possible to create an instance of the abstract `XmlWriter` class. When you call the `Create` method, it will create an instance of one of the classes that inherit from `XmlWriter`. For example calling `Create` for a stream will return an instance of the `XmlWellFormedWriter` class.

The purpose of having a `Create` method to get an instance, is that it can use different classes that fit best depending on what you are trying to do. You tell the framework to create an instance of an appropriate class, so that you don't have to worry about it.