# PowerShell - Prevent Indentation on exported XML file when using LoadXml

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm writing a script at the moment, the main aim of which is to locally interrogate a series of XML files on a target computer and re-create them if they are found to be corrupted or missing for whatever reason.

The problem that I'm having is that there is a particular XML file used by the FileZilla Server application that has no XML declaration and no indentation on it's nodes. As these values are static, I simply created a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` variable and copied the data within a working XML file and pasted it into the argument parentheses of the `.LoadXml()` function without indentation, like so;

```
$xmlFileZillaServer= New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $xmlFileZillaServer.LoadXml('
<FileZillaServer>
<Settings>
<Item name="Serverport" type="numeric">21</Item>
<Item name="Number of Threads" type="numeric">2</Item>
<Item name="Maximum user count" type="numeric">0</Item>
<Item name="Timeout" type="numeric">120</Item>
<Item name="No Transfer Timeout" type="numeric">120</Item>
                     etcetera...
```

However, the output of the XML is indented, as follows;

```
<FileZillaServer>
  <Settings>
    <Item name="Serverport" type="numeric">21</Item>
    <Item name="Number of Threads" type="numeric">2</Item>
    <Item name="Maximum user count" type="numeric">0</Item>
    <Item name="Timeout" type="numeric">120</Item>
    <Item name="No Transfer Timeout" type="numeric">120</Item>
                     etcetera...
```

How can I stop `LoadXml` from putting this indentation in automatically? Or am I going to have to use an `XmlTextWriter` object to write the XML manually and specify the indentation configuration during the write process?

Comment: It's not the `LoadXml()` method that adds the indentation, the document is automatically formatted when you `Save()` it. So yes, you *will* need to use a custom `XmlTextWriter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this issue through a combination of trial-and-error and having a browse through other StackOverflow threads. Essentially, when I set the `Indent` property to `$false` made the XML document write on one long line.

Having had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094180/indentation-and-new-line-command-for-xmlwriter-in-c-sharp) thread for the `XmlTextWriter` class in a C# thread, you instead need to set `Indent` to `$true` and then set the `IndentChars` value to be nothing (`''`) - see below for my method:

```
$xmlWriterSettings= New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlWriterSettings.Indent= $true
$xmlWriterSettings.IndentChars= ''
$xmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration= $true

### INITIALISE XML WRITER ###
$xmlWriter= [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create("C:\FileZilla Server.xml",$xmlWriterSettings)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or am I going to have to use an XmlTextWriter object to write the XML manually and specify the indentation configuration during the write process?

Yes, or rather, an `XmlWriter` class with a custom `XmlWriterSettings` object:

```
# Create a new settings object and configure settings
$XmlWriterSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$XmlWriterSettings.Indent = $false
$XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $true

# Create a new writer with the settings above
$XmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create("C:\output.xml",$XmlWriterSettings)

# Use the writer to save the document
$XmlFileZillaServer.Save($XmlWriter)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I figured that was the case but I appreciate your assistance :)

Comment: Actually, having had a look at this, setting the `Indent` option to `$false` makes the `XMLTextWriter` object output the values on one line.