# How do I generate the following Xml code in C# with XMLWriterClass?

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

I'm trying to get this:

```
      <ATCWaypointEnd id="KLKP">
      </ATCWaypointEnd>
```

But i get this:

```
      <ATCWaypointEnd id="KLKP"></ATCWaypointEnd>
```

Here is my Code:

```
      writer.WriteStartElement("ATCWaypointEnd");
      writer.WriteStartAttribute("id");
      writer.WriteString(ICAO);
      writer.WriteFullEndElement();
```

Comment: What is `ICAO`? (The comments in German unfortunately don't help here.) If you could provide a [mcve] that would be really helpful.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? The new line?. I think the library return a formated `XML`, so you can't create a new line (which is irrelevant).

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: CAO is a string variable.

Comment: @J.F. Yes the new line.

Comment: "A string variable" really doesn't tell us much. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indentation and new line command for XMLwriter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094180/indentation-and-new-line-command-for-xmlwriter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a class to represent your XML file and then use serialization. That way you can let the framework create the XML elements and you can easily specify whether it should contain line breaks or not (indentation).

You can also use an external tool to generate your POCO classes, for example: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Using the piece of xml you provided:

```
// The class representing the XML file
[XmlRoot(ElementName="ATCWaypointEnd")]
public class ATCWaypointEnd 
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

// The method that will return the object as a XML string
public static string GenerateXml(ATCWaypointEnd obj)
{
    string xml;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ATCWaypointEnd));
        
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, encoding);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; // Here

        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        xml = encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
    return xml;
}
```

And then in your code you can use like this:

```
var obj = new ATCWaypointEnd();
obj.Id = "KLKP";

var xml = GenerateXml(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommend. 
I'm no programmer, do you have an complete example how i can use a class for that?

Comment: First of all, you need to define the class that will represent your XML. There are tools where you can input your complete xml and it will return de c# class, like the one I mentioned. After that, you can use the XmlSerializer class to generate the XML in a string representation, like the method provided in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, i will try this

Comment: If it solved your problem, please appreciate marking as solution. If not, let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: I have tried to create the class, but i get an error with them.

Comment: Ok, just a sec.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224817/how-do-i-generate-the-following-xml-code-in-c-with-xmlwriterclass try here

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("ATCWaypointEnd");
writer.WriteAttributeString("id", ICAO); 
writer.WriteString(System.Environment.NewLine);
writer.WriteFullEndElement();
```

See below for full code:

Add the following "using" statements:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
```

**Option 1:**

```
private void WriteXmlData(string ICAO, string filename)
{

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
    settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;

    string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);


    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirName))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Output folder doesn't exist. Creating.");

        //create folder if it doesn't exist
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
    }

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();

        writer.WriteStartElement("ATCWaypointEnd");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("id", ICAO);
        writer.WriteString(System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.WriteFullEndElement(); 

        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Close();
        writer.Dispose();
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
WriteXmlData("KLKP", @"C:\Temp\test.xml");
```

**Option 2:**

```
private string WriteXmlData(string ICAO)
{
    string xmlOutput = string.Empty;

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
    settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;


    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            writer.WriteStartElement("ATCWaypointEnd");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("id", ICAO); 
            writer.WriteString(System.Environment.NewLine);
            writer.WriteFullEndElement(); 

            writer.WriteEndDocument();

            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }

        //reset position
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            //put XML into string
            xmlOutput = sr.ReadToEnd();

            //clean up
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }

        //clean up
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
    }

    return xmlOutput;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string output = WriteXmlData("KLKP");
```