# Xml not remembering the line break before child elements?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file which is like so.

```
<Root>
  <Child123>
   more nodes inside 
   </Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
</Root>
```

My code is generating this file which is not correctly formatting its forgetting to place a hard return at only the `<Cild123>`. You will see on line 2 the 3 line Child123 is starting on Line 2 when it should be on Line 3?

```
<Root>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123><Child123>

  more nodes inside

  </Child123><Child123>
 more nodes inside
</Child123>
</Root>
```

This is my code I read the file into a list view and allow the user to pick some lines then I click generate, this then allows the above file to be generated

```
public static string Seralize<T>(T dataToSerlize)
{
   var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   ns.Add("", "");
   var seralize = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerlize.GetType());
   var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
   settings.Indent = true;
   settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
   settings.NewLineChars = "\n";          
   settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;

   using (var stream = new StringWriter())
   {
       using (var test =  XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
       {
           seralize.Serialize(test, dataToSerlize, ns);
           return stream.ToString();
       }                
   }
}
```

But as you see its not keeping the formatting correct in the generated xml file how to I ensure that it retains the flow of the first xml

PS I also tried

```
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF-8;
```

Which I thought may be the issue.

I also tried

```
settings.NewLineChars = "\n";
```

But still no joy.

Comment: You need to use &#13; and not \n, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding

Comment: @ArunKumar: OP doesn't want to insert a newline in text. He wants to insert a newline before a tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indentation and new line command for XMLwriter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094180/indentation-and-new-line-command-for-xmlwriter-in-c-sharp). Looks like you may want to use the `XmlTextWriter` instead of `XmlWriter`.

Comment: I think the issue is where `Seralize()` is called. The given code only serializes a single datum. How are many datums put together?

Comment: If you set `settings.Indent=true` then you're giving the serializer control over the whitespace formatting in the result.

Comment: If i dont set ident then it all on one line the xml  @MichaelKay

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to focus your efforts on generating valid XML and let `XDocument` handle the formatting.  Assuming your generated XML is valid, you can do this with it:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

string rawXml = 
    @"<Root>
        <Child123></Child123>
        <Child123></Child123><Child123>
        </Child123><Child123>
        </Child123>
      </Root>";

XDocument formattedXml = XDocument.Parse(rawXml);
```

The output of `formattedXml.ToString()` is:

```
<Root>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
  <Child123></Child123>
</Root>
```

Comment: If u notice mine is a object not  string not wanting to use xdocument

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but your `Serialize` method does return a string.  My thought was you could take that string and feed it into the method I provided.